# Why isn't my box2D(flash) object moving correctly under gravity?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d, game-physics

I am creating a world in flash using box2d. I have done this before and I am sure it is something simple but I cannot identify it.

```
import Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2;
import Box2D.Dynamics.b2World;
import Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef;
import Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body;
import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2CircleShape;
import Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef;
import Box2D.Dynamics.b2Fixture;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;


//variables
var startVelocity:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(50, 0);

//world defintion
var gravity:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(0,10);
var world:b2World = new b2World(gravity, true);

//object physics object
var objectBodyDef:b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
objectBodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
var objectBody:b2Body = world.CreateBody(objectBodyDef);
objectBody.SetLinearVelocity(startVelocity);
//object shape definition. Change to box later
var objectShape:b2CircleShape = new b2CircleShape(5);
var objectFixtureDef:b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
objectFixtureDef.shape = objectShape;
var objectFixture:b2Fixture = objectBody.CreateFixture(objectFixtureDef);


//outlines for objects
graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xff0000);

//Create world timing
var stepTimer:Timer = new Timer(0.025 * 1000);
stepTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);

stepTimer.start();



function onTick(a_event:TimerEvent):void{
    graphics.moveTo(objectBody.GetPosition().x, objectBody.GetPosition().y);
    world.Step(0.25, 10, 10);
    graphics.lineTo(objectBody.GetPosition().x, objectBody.GetPosition().y);
    trace("objectBody x: " + objectBody.GetPosition().x +" objectBody y: " + objectBody.GetPosition().y);
}
```

I am doing this from the timeline so The issue is not anything to do with document class.

The above code works fine for the most part however the "object" does not move in a parabola as one would expect. It stops moving right when x is about 12. This happens regardless of what value I use fore the x component of the starting velocity vector. 
What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: the object has no mass when you set its velocity. Box2D deals with object as they are not as what they are gonna be, your object has no fixture when you set its velocity so it has no mass.

Comment: @BotMaster are you saying that I should move the line 
     objectBody.SetLinearVelocity(startVelocity);
lower down? I tried that but the result is the same.